# UIBarButtonItem minus sign

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, uinavigationcontroller, uibarbuttonitem

Is there a UIBarButtonSystem icon that is "-" minus? Opposite of this: [image]

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

No, All the available icons are [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIBarButtonItem_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/c/tdef/UIBarButtonSystemItem). You can use a custom view instead.

Answer (score 1):

I use from the menu Edit -> Emoji & Symbols the EM DASH symbol. It's like a minus but wider. For example:

```
navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem  = UIBarButtonItem(title: "—", style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(removeColumn))
```

[image: The EM DASH symbol]

Answer (score 0):

To get minus, you could create an custom button with minus image,

if you look into the below apple documentation for available system UIBar.. buttons

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIBarButtonItem_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/c/tdef/UIBarButtonSystemItem

there is no minus kind of button available So you will have to create by yourself.

Use the below code to create an button with minus image, create `UIBarButtonItem` by adding your button as custom view,

```
UIImage *image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"minus.png"];
UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
button.bounds = CGRectMake( 0, 0, image.size.width, image.size.height );    
[button setImage:image forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[button addTarget:self action:@selector(Minus) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];    
UIBarButtonItem *barButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:button];
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = barButtonItem;
[barButtonItem release];
```